# Ruby on Rails - SerializationTypeMismatch error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model named `Style` with a text column that's serialized as a hash. Here's the code from my model:

```
# style.rb
serialize :acctbookings, Hash
```

And here's the code attempting to update this column in an instance of `Style` with a hash:

```
updatehash = { "abc" => "123" }
s.update(acctbookings: updatehash)
```

And here is the error I'm getting:

```
ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch in LoaderController#update_majors
Attribute was supposed to be a Hash, but was a String. -- ""
```

I have verified that the class of variable I am feeding into the update is in fact `Hash`, not `String`.

Thanks in advance!